# Empty password in form authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an asp.net application that uses a form authentification . In my model i'd like to add my session account

```
public class Users
    {
        public string name;
        public string password;
        public string mail;
       public  Users()
        {
            Membership.CreateUser("Lamloumi", "");
        }
        Users(string _name, string _pwd, string _mail) {
            name = _name; password = _pwd; mail = _mail;
        }
    }
```

in the `web.config`

```
  <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/login" ></forms>
    </authentication>
```

in the controller i had:

```
   public ActionResult login() {
            Models.Users _u = new Models.Users();
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
```

My session admin account have no password, when  i run the application a exception appears indicates that i have to put a password to my user.

So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Why not just workaround the problem by using a *standard* password?

Comment: What do you mean by standard password?

Comment: As in a password that you know. Why must you use an empty password?

Comment: How do you suggest to modify my code? put it as answer plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Membership.CreateUser("Lamloumi", "PasswordOnlyKnownToMe");
```